# SQL query join tables data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables `Users` and `TimeSheets`, `Timesheets` table has column `UserId` which is users id form users table obviously :)

**Logic**

And I'm trying to get all data of `Timesheets` table plus **just name of user from users table** but somehow it seems like my query is other way around!

Now I know this might be a simple query but I personally have no idea about SQL (my bad!)

Here is my query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTimeSheets]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        t.Id, t.Enter_time, t.Exit_Time, t.Total, t.Date, 
        t.Month, t.Year, u.Name AS username
    FROM 
        TimeSheets t
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
        Users u ON u.Id = t.UserId
    GROUP BY 
        t.Id, t.Enter_time, t.Exit_Time, t.Total, t.Date, 
        t.Month, t.Year, u.Name
END;
```

And here is screenshot of returned data:

[image: one]

As you can see I get my users names without any data being existed in timesheets table!

This view supposed to get timesheets table and then username of each row from users.

**Update**

Here is my timesheets table schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimeSheets]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [UserId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Enter_time] TIME NOT NULL, 
    [Exit_Time] TIME NULL, 
    [Total] TIME NULL, 
    [Date] DATE NULL, 
    [Month] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    [Year] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 

    CONSTRAINT [FK_TimeSheets_Users] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users]([Id])
);
```

And here is users table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] 
(
    [Id]       INT            NOT NULL,
    [UserType] NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Name]     NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Please enter the sample data as well as the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want an `INNER` join and since you are not doing any aggregation there is no need for `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t.*, 
       u.Name AS username
FROM TimeSheets t
INNER JOIN Users u 
ON u.Id = t.UserId;
```

By doing an `INNER` join you get results only when there is a match between 2 rows in the 2 tables.

Comment: Thank you, I just changed select part to `SELECT t.Id, t.Enter_time, t.Exit_Time, t.Total, t.Date, t.Month, t.Year,` in order to match my view table otherwise it would have additional `userId` column in my view.

Comment: @mafortis fine, but I noticed that Name is not defined as UNIQUE in the table Users, so maybe you should keep userId just in case there are 2 users with the same Name.

Comment: yes I have username column as well but because i wasn't using it for this query I didn't mention it. That column is unique, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, in order to access users, you have to give the user table to TimeSheets LEFT JOIN so that if the user profile is empty.

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Enter_time, t.Exit_Time, t.Total, t.Date, t.Month, t.Year, u.Name as username
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN TimeSheets t ON u.Id = t.UserId
GROUP BY t.Id,t.Enter_time,t.Exit_Time,t.Total, t.Date, t.Month, t.Year, u.Name
```